# Forcing let to bind to a function instead of a value

Tags: f#

I have this piece of code that is supposed to generate random names:

```
let generateName =
    let rnd = System.Random()
    let c1 = rnd.Next(65, 90) |> System.Convert.ToChar |> string
    let c2 = rnd.Next(65, 90) |> System.Convert.ToChar |> string
    let n = rnd.Next(0, 999)  |> string
    c1 + c2 + n
```

This evaluates to a string, which isn't quite what i want. Adding a unit-Parameter fixes the problem, but now i have to call my function like a C# function:

```
let myFunc() =
    "Hello"

myFunc()
```

Is this how i have to do it, or is there a more idiomatic way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, that's how F# works.  Every function in F# must have one parameter (functions with multiple parameters are split into multiple functions with one parameter returning an intermediate function), and every function must return something, even if it's unit.

Comment: Never thought about it this way, makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR:** `()` in this context has an entirely different meaning than it has in C#, so do not format it the same way as in C# – use `let myFunc () =` and `myFunc ()` instead, which better reflects actual semantics and will in turn clarify how you think about and understand the code.

---

In C#, `()` means an empty set of parameters (for function/constructor definitions) or arguments (for function/constructor call-sites); i.e., it defines or invokes a *nullary* function. In F#, `()` is a literal of type `unit`, akin to how `42` is a literal of type `int`; i.e., it is a value in and of itself, just as `[]` is a value for an empty list. This difference has lots of little implications.

In F#, when you *define* a `let`-function with only `()` for parameters, as in `let myFunc() =`, you are actually using pattern-matching syntax to define a *unary* function with a parameter of type `unit` (*not* a nullary function!). This particular instance of pattern-matching is so taken for granted that many people do not realize that it's pattern-matching in the first place; but, in fact, defining a function as `let myFunc () =` rather than as `let myFunc (_:unit) =` is akin to having `let myFunc [] =` rather than `let myFunc (x:'a list) =` (and subsequently asserting that `x` is empty).

And in F#, when you *invoke* a `let`-function with `()`, as in `myFunc ()`, you are not denoting 'no arguments'; you are in fact supplying an argument of type `unit`, whose singular value is so often used that it has its own literal syntax: `()`.

To convince yourself `unit` is different from 'no parameters/arguments', and is in fact just another parameter/argument like any other, consider the fact that the following is completely legal:

```
let myFunc() (i:int) (_:unit*unit) = i
let n = myFunc() 42((),())
printfn "%d" n
```

As you can see, giving `unit` special whitespace treatment is silly given that it's *not special*. ;-]

Summarily, since it is usual (necessary?) to separate any *named* parameter/argument with whitespace, it is then **idiomatic** to be consistent and do the same with *symbolic* patterns/values:

```
let myFunc () =
    "Hello"

myFunc ()
```

Comment: "idiomatic" might be a strong word. The FSharp.Core source doesn't use this style for instance.  https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/tree/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core. I've personally jumped back and forth between styles and ended up with the non-space variant.  While `unit` is an arg, I find it has a special meaning -- "run this function".

Comment: In fact I once went so far as to include an extra `()` in all functions, so that with e.g. `let f()=rand()` and `g x () = rand()+x`, `f` and `g 1` could be treated the same. However that doesn't work well when using with e.g. `map`; the extra parameter threw it off  The difference? Side effects. So ideally, anything with side effects, I'd add the extra `()` even if other params existed. Sadly it looks pretty silly in F# so I've moved to Haskell where it makes far more sense and is differentiated by necessity.

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly how it works. A function with no "useful" parameters needs to have a `unit` parameter to actually make it a function.

It is not uncommon to separate the function name and `()` by a space to make it look a bit less method-y and more function-y, but that's purely cosmetic.